# Nuget nuspec specify private dependency

Tags: nuget

Essentially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329933/nuget-specify-dependency-without-references-being-added).

I have a NuGet package that has a dependency, it gets installed alongside the package. 
However, NuGet adds both the package and recursive dependency package as a reference.

MsBuild has the <private> tag to distinguish one type of dependency from the other, has NuGet been changed in the last 5 years to support this?

I can't find any hints that it does.

Tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [PackageReference format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) of referencing NuGet packages (instead of packages.config), it allows to control the assets consumed by the project and forwarded to dependencies per referenced package. This also allows to sepcify that all assets of the package are "private" which causes the reference to not be added to the packed nupkg:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="My.BuildTimeOnly.Dependency" 
                    Version="1.2.3"
                    PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That's strange, shouldn't the package itself manifest what is it's private dependency vs. its public dependency? It's already doable through "reference" tag in .nuspec for dlls in the lib folder, it's just not doable for NuGet dependencies.